# LLVM store operand must be a pointer

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to store the value of a global variable into a local variable in a function in my custom LLVM Pass.

the global variable is defined as

```
GlobalVariable* gvar_int32_test = new GlobalVariable(
        /*Module=*/     M, 
        /*Type=*/       IntegerType::get(M.getContext(), 32),
        /*isConstant=*/ false,
        /*Linkage=*/    GlobalValue::CommonLinkage,
        /*Initializer=*/0, // has initializer, specified below
        /*Name=*/"global_test_var");
        gvar_int32_test->setAlignment(4);
```

The local variable I intend to store into is originally being used as the store location for a call instruction. I attempt to get this value using

```
Value* localVar = ci->getOperand(0) //ci is the call instruction
```

using an IR builder, I attempt to write a store instruction as:

```
StoreInst* strLocIns = builder.CreateStore(gvar_int32_test, localVar, false);
//my intent is to create an instruction that means localvar = globalvar;
```

Similarly, earlier in the code I attempt to store the value in the return instruction of a called function to the global variable

```
Value* value = ri->getReturnValue(); //ri is the return instruction
// Some more code, including setting the IR builder insertion point
StoreInst* strIns = builder.CreateStore(value, gvar_int32_test, false);
//here the intention is globalvar = localvar
```

when I try to compile my with my pass included, I get the error:

```
Store operand must be a pointer.
    store i32* @global_test_var, i32 %5
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Both of the arguments for the variables that I pass to the IR builder are pointers, but the IR is somehow broken. I think that i32 %5 should be i32* %5 to indicate that %5 points to an i32, but I don't know how to fix my code to make that happen. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Swap the operands of `store`: first is what and second - where.